# Tic Tac Toe Winner Function is Buggy

Tags: python

I'm a beginner (somewhat) in Python. In my Tic Tac Toe Game, I'm stuck at the winner(board) function, because whenever I run the program and place an X anywhere, it immediately says "Y O U  W O N !" When I removed the code under the make_computer_move(board) to try and debug my winner(board) function, the diagonal from the top right to bottom left doesn't work, but the top left to bottom right winner determination code works. Here is my code below:

```
"""
    Author: Victor Xu
    
    Date: Jan 12, 2021

    Description: An implementation of the game Tic-Tac-Toe in Python,
    using a nested list, and everything else we've learned this quadmester!
"""

import random


def winner(board):
    """This function accepts the Tic-Tac-Toe board as a parameter.
    If there is no winner, the function will return the empty string "".
    If the user has won, it will return 'X', and if the computer has
    won it will return 'O'."""

    # Check rows for winner
    for row in range(3):
        if (board[row][0] == board[row][1] == board[row][2]) and \
                (board[row][0] != " "):
            return board[row][0]

    # COMPLETE THE REST OF THE FUNCTION CODE BELOW
    for col in range(3):
        if (board[0][col] == board[1][col] == board[2][col]) and \
                (board[0][col] != " "):
            return board[0][col]

    # Check diagonal (top-left to bottom-right) for winner
    if (board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2]) and \
            (board[0][0] != " "):
        return board[0][0]

    # Check diagonal (bottom-left to top-right) for winner
    if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0]) and \
            (board[0][0] != " "):
        return board[0][0]

    # No winner: return the empty string
    return ""


def display_board(board):
    """This function accepts the Tic-Tac-Toe board as a parameter.
    It will print the Tic-Tac-Toe board grid (using ASCII characters)
    and show the positions of any X's and O's.  It also displays
    the column and row numbers on top and beside the board to help
    the user figure out the coordinates of their next move.
    This function does not return anything."""

    print("   0   1   2")
    print("0: " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2])
    print("  ---+---+---")
    print("1: " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2])
    print("  ---+---+---")
    print("2: " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2])
    print()


def make_user_move(board):
    """This function accepts the Tic-Tac-Toe board as a parameter.
    It will ask the user for a row and column.  If the row and
    column are each within the range of 0 and 2, and that square
    is not already occupied, then it will place an 'X' in that square."""

    valid_move = False
    while not valid_move:
        row = int(input("What row would you like to move to (0-2):"))
        col = int(input("What col would you like to move to (0-2):"))
        if (0 <= row <= 2) and (0 <= col <= 2) and (board[row][col] == " "):
            board[row][col] = 'X'
            valid_move = True
        else:
            print("Sorry, invalid square. Please try again!\n")


def make_computer_move(board):
    """This function accepts the Tic-Tac-Toe board as a parameter.
    It will randomly pick row and column values between 0 and 2.
    If that square is not already occupied it will place an 'O'
    in that square.  Otherwise, another random row and column
    will be generated."""

    computer_valid_move = False
    while not computer_valid_move:
        row = random.randint(0, 2)
        col = random.randing(0, 2)
        if (0 <= row <= 2) and (0 <= col <= 2) and (board[row][col] == " "):
            board[row][col] = 'O'
            computer_valid_move = True


def main():
    """Our Main Game Loop:"""

    free_cells = 9
    users_turn = True
    ttt_board = [[" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "]]

    while not winner(ttt_board) and (free_cells > 0):
        display_board(ttt_board)
        if users_turn:
            make_user_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        else:
            make_computer_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        free_cells -= 1

    display_board(ttt_board)
    if (winner(ttt_board) == 'X'):
        print("Y O U   W O N !")
    elif (winner(ttt_board) == 'O'):
        print("I   W O N !")
    else:
        print("S T A L E M A T E !")
    print("\n*** GAME OVER ***\n")


# Start the game!
main()
```

TL;DR

Please check out the top right to bottom left diagonal win determination code and the issue whenever I place down an X and it says "YOU WON!"

Comment: By transitivity, you can write `a == b == c != d` instead of `a == b == c and a != d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bottom-left to top-right diagonal check is wrong. You're checking that the correct diagonal elements are equal to each other, but then you check the wrong corner element to see if it's not a space. It should be:

```
    # Check diagonal (bottom-left to top-right) for winner
    if (board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0]) and \
            (board[0][2] != " "):
        return board[0][2]
```

Comment: Oh my god, I thought I was correct there... Thank you so much for explaining this to me, I really appreciate it! I'll accept this as the answer when the cooldown ends :) Again, thank you!

Comment: Writing `board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] != " "` would have prevented this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

First: I see you have a typo ("randing", I guess it was randint again as the previous line?
Second: The code runs fine here up until the point where I have placed my first X where everything crashes (AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'randing' due to the randing error)
Third: After changing the typo for you, I finished the game and won against the machine (luckily, until you/someone (hehe I might have once) implement AI in the game).

Best of luck ahead with Python, it's such a fun language but hard when something goes wrong.

Regards

Comment: Yeah, I saw the typo after I corrected the error in my winner(board) function. Lol!